# Independence between random vector and event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, uniform-distribution

> Let $U_1, U_2$ and $U_3$ be three independent uniformly $(0, 1)$ random variables.
>
> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a sequence of independent uniformly $(0, 1)$ random variables.
>
> Consider that $X_i$ and $U_j$ are independents, for all $i,j$.
>
> Show that the event $\{U_1 > U_2 > U_3\}$ is independent of the $(U_{(3)},X_{(1)})$, where $U_{(3)} = \max\{U_1,U_2,U_3\}$ and $X_{(1)} = \min\{X_1,...,X_n\}$.

I have no idea to start. How'd be the definition of independence between events and random variables?

Comment: As for your last question: the rv. $X$ is independent of an event $A$ if all events $B$ defined in terms of $X$ are independent of $A$, such as $B=[X\lt t]$, or $B=[X\in  S]$, or most generally, for all $B$ in the sigma field $\mathcal{F}(X)$ generated by $X$

Comment: You also need independence between $U_k$ and$X_j$ for all indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event and a random variable are independent if for all supported values of the random variable, the conditional expectation of the event given the variable equals the margial probability of the event.

In short you need to establish whether: $${\forall u\in(0;1)~\forall x\in(0;1):\\\quad\mathsf P(\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\})=\mathsf P(\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\}\mid u{=}\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^3,x{=}\min\{X_j\}_{j=1}^n)}$$

Comment: $\min\{X_j)_{j=1}^n\}$ is independent of $\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\}$. How can I prove that $\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\}$ and $\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^3$ are independent, or
$P(\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\}\mid u{=}\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^3) = P(\{U_1{>}U_2{>}U_3\})$ ?

Comment: Use symmetry.  @PedroSalgato

Comment: how can I use? @graham-kemp

Comment: Argue that that $\mathsf P(\{U_1>U_2>U_3\}\mid u{=}\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^3)=\mathsf P(\{U_3>U_1>U_2\}\mid u{=}\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^3)$ and so forth, by symmetry. @Pedro-Salgado